# Difference between linear maps in the commutative or non-commutative case?

Tags: abstract-algebra

i was reading Algebra-Serge Lang book and i found a part that i don't understand, can you help me? It is the remark in page 643. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi6Xa.png)

Comment: Please [do not use image for the essential part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference in the definitions of the maps themselves, but there is a subtlety in how they behave.

Given a division ring $D$ and $a\in D$, left multiplication by $a$ always generates a *right* $D$ linear map on $D$.

If, instead, you suppose that left multiplication by every element of $D$ produces a left $D$ linear map, then necessarily $D$ is commutative, which was not the point to be made.

Now, if we were composing two in a row, I'd say that $f_{ab}(v)=(ab)v=a(bv)=a(f_b(v))=f_a(f_b(v))=(f_a\circ f_b)(v)$.

Similarly, *right* multiplication by $a$ (let's call that $g_a$) always makes a *left* $D$ linear map.  In that case,

$g_{ab}(v)=v(ab)=(va)b=g_a(v)b=g_b(g_a(v))=(g_b\circ g_a)(v)$

In the second case, you can see the multiplication is "twisted" since $g_{ab}=g_bg_a$, but in the earlier case $f_{ab}=f_af_b$. Mine doesn't turn out twisted when multiplication happens on the left, but it does turn out twisted when the multiplication is happening on the right.

Now, the difference between your book and what I said could perhaps be that the author uses the opposite convention to compose maps that I do. As you can see, I interpret $(f\circ g)(v)=f(g(v))$, but if the author meant that $(f\circ g)(v)=g(f(v))$, then they would be making the same point I am above (just in different notation.) With that composition convention, $f$ would be the untwisted one, and $g$ would be the twisted one.

Answer (score -1):

if $f$ is a D-linear map, then for $\lambda \in D$ we must have
$$
f(\lambda v) = \lambda f(v) \tag{1}
$$
where $v$ is the (single) basis element for the D-vector space E.

for elements $a, b \in D$ and the D-linear (premultiplication) maps $f_a, f_b$ we have:

$$
f_af_b(v) = f_a(bv) = bf_a(v) = bav
$$

where the second equality results from application of the rule (1)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i didn't understand the part that tells the difference between linear maps in commutative and noncommutative case.

Comment: Left multiplication produces a left $D$ linear map for all $\lambda$ iff $D$ is already a field, which is not intended. Left multiplication always produces a *right* $D$ linear map, though, which was probably the intention.